CKKS encoding. Why not just use fft
I am studying the ckks scheme from this blog post. In the vanilla encoding part we want to encode a complex vector of size N to a complex polynomial of degree N-1. This of course is possible if we consider the elements of the vector to be evaluations of the polynomial we are trying to find.
My problem is with the choice of the evaluation points. Specifically in the blog post they choose the roots of the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_M=X^N-1$ where $M=2N$. Those roots happen to be the odd powers of the M-th root of unity so the evaluation points are $\xi^1,\xi^3,...,\xi^{2N-1}$ where $\xi=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{M}}$.
My question is, why can we not just use the points $\xi^0,\xi^1,...,\xi^{N-1}$. If we do this the encoding and decoding becomes IDFT and DFT respectively, instead of solving a linear equation and doing polynomial evaluations.
Furthermore the Fourier transform and inverse can be even more optimized using the FFT to have complexity O(long).
Can you explain to me why the points have to be roots of the cyclotomic polynomial?

Check the original paper where they do indeed use FFT.
